# Matlab: A plot with ksdensity to have a pseudo 3D look

Tags: matlab, 3d, histogram

I would like to make a histogram plot using ksdensity in 3D.
My plot looks similar to the example here;

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fit-kernel-distributions-to-grouped-data-using-ksdensity.html

In my example I have 15 different histograms, and this plot in 2D is very congested. I am trying to space them out along a 3rd axis so they can be observed better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the explicit solution of your problem:

```
figure(1)
hold on; grid on
for i = 1:15
    path = ['tmp_',num2str(i),'.out'];
    fid = fopen(path, 'r');
    a = textscan(fid,'%f');

    % Appearantly the first line is a string in some of your files
    % This if statement will take care of it ;)
    if isempty(a{1})
        fgetl(fid);
        a = textscan(fid,'%f');
    end
    tmp = a{1};
    % Some of your files (all but one I think) contain element numbering
    % This if statement takes care of it ;)
    if length(tmp) > 180000
        tmp = tmp(2:2:end);
    end
    fclose(fid);
    [f, xi] = ksdensity(tmp);
    plot3(xi, ones(length(f))*i, f)
end
view(3)
```

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing. But, you understood exactly what I am getting at in figure(1). I do not understand how to read in my data my to x(i,:) though.
so far this is what I have...and a picture of my 2D plot is below:
`xi = linspace(80,150,100);
figure(1);
hold on; grid on;
x = zeros(180000,15);
for i = 1:15
    x(i,:) = ;   % unsure how to read in my data
    f(i,:) = ksdensity(tmp_(i).out,xi);
    plot3(xi, ones(length(f(i,:)),1)*i, f(i,:))
end
view(3)
y = 1:15;`
http://picpaste.com/pics/untitled-2QXgdcFa.1458704706.jpg

Comment: Where do you get tmp_ from?

Comment: That is the batch name of my data. tmp_1 through tmp_15

Comment: Can I access the data? Is it available anywhere?

Comment: Yes, i uploaded it to a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jefreovr266cveo/AACB7DPcw6DC02upTQhdVWV9a?dl=0) folder.

Comment: The explicit solution is now in the answer. Let me know if you have any problems with it. If all works as expected, please "accept" the answer and upvote ;P

Comment: I used awk in a script to remove the first line of the data files. But that 1 file escaped me. I actually used the previous code and made the plot... long story short, both sets of code produce the same image so I'm ecstatic. Although, I might need clarification on the first "if", but let me play with it and see if I can figure it out.